# How can I show full text for a legend on a single line using Google Chart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, legend

I am new google charts and angularjs,i made two pie charts on same dive horizontally on same height and width.Pie charts are fine both of the same size and aligned but the legend label which i have is little long and google charts by default cut it off and place the in second row:
make sure the width of the chart increasing solution not worked for me because i have tow pie charts if i increase the chart width then 2nd pie charts move below i want it both of them on same row.
here is sample code in Index.HTML:

```
         <head>
           <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
           <script src="script.js"></script>
           <script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
         </head>

         <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
           <div style="padding-left:100px">
                my pig pie chart</div>
         <div google-chart chart="chart" style="width:400,height:300"></div>
         </body>
```

Script.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'googlechart' ]);

     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      var chart1 = {};
      chart1.type = "PieChart";
      chart1.data = [
       ['Component', 'cost'],
       ['Software and hardware', 50000],
       ['Hardware', 80000]
  ];
       chart1.data.push(['Services',20000]);
        chart1.options = {
       'legend':'right',
        'width':400,
        'height':300
   };
  chart1.formatters = {
      number : [{
      columnNum: 1,
      pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
    }]
  };

   $scope.chart = chart1;

     $scope.aa=1*$scope.chart.data[1][1];
    $scope.bb=1*$scope.chart.data[2][1];
    $scope.cc=1*$scope.chart.data[3][1];
});
```

you can see the legend label cutting off and displayed in tow line or 3 line as the string goes longer .it should be on same line at least 20 characters.

any suggestion guide me how can i do this.thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no programmatically solution, you must ensure that there is enough space for the legend.

In your special case it will work when you adjust the width of the `chartArea`(without setting the width the API will use some padding).

You should also adjust the font-size for the legend.

```
   chart1.options = {
       chartArea:{height:'200',
                  width:'100%'},
       legend:{textStyle:{fontSize:10}},
       width:400,
       height:300
   };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eVIEWdRf6VFv9XhZM6z7?p=preview